# Progressive measurability intuition from Bichteler's *Stochastic integration with jumps* book

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

In the *Stochastic Integration with Jumps* Bichteler gives a very intuitive definition of progressive measurability I've never seen before:

[image: Quote from Page 25]

Although I like this intuition very much, I cannot find a nice example of such measurable property of path snippets $( X_s )_{0 \leq s \leq t}$, which can sense non-progressiveness of $Z_t$. Can you give such example?

---

**Another related question.** This intuition *suggests* that separable processes should be progressive automatically. But this is not true, isn't it? I couldn't find any references for this...

Answer (score 1):

Progressiveness is also (perhap mainly) about joint measurability in $t$ and $\omega$. To take an extreme example, if $\mathcal F_t=\mathcal F$ for all $t$, then a process $\{X_t: 0\le t <\infty\}$ is adapted if each $X_t$ is a random variable (i.e., $\mathcal F$-measurable) but progressive only if $(t,\omega)\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is $\mathcal B^{•}[0,\infty)\otimes\mathcal F$ measurable.

Progressive measurability permits the application of Fubini's theorem, for example: If $Z$ is progressive and bounded, then for each $t>0$, the integral $I_t(\omega):=\int_0^t Z_s(\omega)\,ds$ exists and defines an $\mathcal F_t$ measurable random variable $I_t$.

Comment: What you wrote is 1) a definition of progressive measurability and 2) one of the most standard consequences of it. I know both, but neither seems to be related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

### Intuition

As @JohnDawkins said, progressive measurability seems connected to Fubini's theorem. For any adapted process $X$, it enables the path-wise integral up to any time $t$ to be adapted, i.e. $\int_0^t X_s ds \in \mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t$.

Your book vaguely mentions that "properties" and "information" of the path that might have been available before the current time $t$ should be available at $\mathcal{F}_t$, but we can clarify the situation with Fubini's theorem.

So let $X$ be a progressively measurable stochastic process, adapted to filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)$. Consider segment $\Gamma = (a, b)$ and associated indicator $Q = (s, \omega) \rightarrow 1_{X(s, \omega) \in \Gamma}$.

For each fixed $s \in (0, \infty)$, $Q_s$ is measurable in $\mathcal{F}_s$ because $\{ Q_s = 1 \} = \{X_s \in \Gamma\} \in \mathcal{F}_s$, hence $Q$ is an adapted stochastic process wrt filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)$. Moreover, restricted to time $(0, t]$, $\{ Q = 1 \} = \{ X \in \Gamma \} \in \mathcal{B}((0, t]) \otimes \mathcal{F_t}$ so that $Q$ is progressively measurable. (Alternatively, since $Q$ is a deterministic function of $X$, $Q$ is measurable whenever $X$ is.)

By Fubini's theorem, for any $0 < t_1 < t_2 < t$, the expression $I = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} Q_s ds$ is measurable in $\mathcal{F_t}$. Note that $I$ is the (random) amount of time that the process $X$ spent inside $\Gamma$ between times $(t_1, t_2)$.

So progressive measurability of $X$ allows us to answer all questions of the form "How much time did $X$ spend in $(a, b)$ during times $(t_1, t_2)$?", at any time $t \ge t_2$.

I believe we also have the converse in the sense that, if all such questions of that form are answerable at $F_t$ for $t \ge t_2$, then $X$ is progressively measurable, but I haven't worked out the technicalities.

By combining indicators, we can get at much more complicated types of "information/properties". An interesting example is "How many times has the progressively measurable continuous process $X$ crossed the line $X = c$ up until the current time $t$?" We can show this question belongs to $\mathcal{F}_t$ as follows.   Let $P^n$ be a sequence of finite partitions of $(0, t]$ such that $P^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \cap (0, t]$. Then for every segment $(q_i^n, q_{i+1}^n)$ in $P^n$ the indicator $I_i^n = 1\left[\int_{q_i^n}^{q_{i+1}^n} 1_{[X_s > c]} ds > 0\right] \cdot 1\left[\int_{q_i^n}^{q_{i+1}^n} 1_{[X_s < c]} ds > 0\right]$ is a random variable in $\mathcal{F_t}$ and answers the question "Did $X$ cross $c$ during $(q_i, q_{i+1})?$". This is because if $X$ crossed $c$, then it must have spent positive amount of time above $c$ and below $c$ in which case both indicators are 1. On the other hand, if $X$ did not cross $c$, then it spent all of its time either above $c$ or below $c$ in which case one of the indicators is $0$. Using similar sorts of gadgets, we can show that for each rational $q \in (0, t)$, the indicator $C_q = 1\left[ X \text{ crosses } c  \text{ at } q \,\right] \in \mathcal{F}_{q + \epsilon} \subset \mathcal{F}_t$. Then the sum $S_n = \sum_1^{N_n} I^n_{i=1} + \sum_{q \not \in \cup_{i=1}^{N_n} (q_i^n, q_{i+1}^n)} C_q$  is a random variable in $\mathcal{F}_t$ which lower bounds the number of crossings during $(0, t]$, since multiple crossings in the same interval $(q_i^n, q_{i+1}^n)$ are counted only once. Since $S_n$ is a sequence of increasing functions, it obtains a limit $S \in \mathcal{F}_t$. So the number of crossings during $(0, t)$ is a random variable in $\mathcal{F}_t$, putting aside some technicalities involving the hypotheses of Fubini's theorem.

The counter-example you gave is a special case of these sorts of questions, since it is equivalent to "Has $X$ spent positive time above $0$ up until the current time $t$?" However, there was a problem with your specific counterexample (see below).

### A problem with your counterexample

Choose some countable sequence $s_1, s_2, \ldots < t$ and let $Y_n = \max_{i \in 1,\ldots n} X(s_i)$. Then $Y_n \in \mathcal{F}_t$ for every $n$ since the $X(s_i)$ are. Then the limit $Y_\infty \in \mathcal{F}_t$ as well. $P(Y_\infty > 0) = 1 - P(Y_\infty \le 0) = 1 - \Pi_{i=1}^\infty P(Y(s_i) \le 0) = 1$, where for the second to last equality I used independence and for the last equality I used the fact that $K^n \rightarrow 0$ for $K \in (0,1)$.

Hence $P(\max_{s \in [0,t]} X(s) > 0) \ge P(Y_\infty > 0) = 1$ so that $P(\max_{s \in [0,t]} X(s) > 0) = 1$.

So we can answer your question (2.) without even looking at the sample path. If you wanted, you could go through your search algorithm, but it wouldn't take long to stumble upon an $s$ such that $X(s) > 0$. The number of attempts would be distributed as a geometric random variable. So question (2.), for this specific process, is not exemplary of "information that can only be learned by examining a path at uncountably many times".

On the other hand, I found the following "nice" example of a measurable adapted process that is not progressively measurable [here](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/nonsense.pdf) as example 16.15. I will outline the construction below, in case the link goes down.

### A "nice" non-progressively measurable process

Let $\Omega$ be the set of lower semicontinuous functions on $(0, \infty)$. For every $p, q  \in \mathbb{Q}^+$, $p < q$, we define the random variable $I_{p,q}(\omega) = \inf_{(p,q)}\omega$ and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the sigma algebra generated by all such $I_{p,q}$. For all $t \in (0, \infty)$, define the function $H_t(\omega) = \omega(t)$.

It can be shown that $H$ is jointly measurable in $((0, \infty) \times \Omega,\, \mathcal{B}(0,\infty) \otimes \mathcal{F})$. Then, given the natural filtration, $H$ is an adapted, measurable stochastic process.

Assume for contradiction that $H$ is progressively measurable. Then $H$ is jointly measurable when restricted to $((0, 1] \times \Omega,\, \mathcal{B}(0,1] \otimes \mathcal{F}_{t=1})$. By Fubini's theorem, $X = \int_0^t H_t dt$ is measurable in $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}_{t=1})$. Since $\mathcal{F}_{t=1} = \sigma(\cup_{s \in (0, 1]} \{ H_{s} \})$, $X$ is a function of $H_{s_1}, \ldots, H_{s_i}, \ldots$ for countably many $s_i \in (0, 1]$.

Now take $\omega = 1$ and $\omega' = 1_O$ where $O$ is an open set of measure $< 1$ which contains all the $s_i$. Then $X(\omega) = X(\omega')$. But the left hand side equals 1, and the right hand side is less than 1, a contradiction.

Comment: Wow! This is a very nice answer. Regarding the problem with my counterexample, don't we need to complete the filtration for this event to be measurable? I mean that it technically doesn't belong to the filtration itself, only to its completion. Unless I am wrong, of course.

Comment: P.S. I am trying to interpret completion as allowing one to use sure-properties (with probability 0 or 1) in answering path-related questions additionally to the information available from $\mathcal{F}_t$.

Comment: Here is how I think about it.

Completion is necessary if you commit to saying $Y_\infty$ is essentially different from $\max_{s \in [0,t]} X_s$ even though they are equal almost everywhere in $\Omega$. This type of distinction is necessary if your interest is in probability theory as an axiomatic system.

On the other hand, if you want to *use* the theory to reason about observable phenomena, we can deal with random variables as equivalence classes under a.e equality. In which case, a random variable is measurable in $\mathcal{F}_t$ if any in its equivalence class are.

Comment: what you say seems to be in accordance with what I said. I just wanted to point out that technically my example is still fine, because the event you've described doesn't belong to $\mathcal{F}_t$ unless it is complete. Another thing is that I haven't seen this notion of measurability relative to $\mathcal{F}_t$ in books. Isn't it equivalent to $\mathcal{F}_t$ being complete?

Comment: For any particular $t$, $\mathcal{F}_t \subset \mathcal{F}$ is a bona fide $\sigma$ algebra of $\Omega$, the definition of measurability works the same. Does that answer your question?

Comment: no, this is not the question. You said above that by "$X$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable" you mean that any of its $\mathbb{P}$-equivalence classes are. And I asked whether this is equivalent to saying that $\mathcal{F}_t$ is complete with respect to $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: Take $\Omega = \{ a, b, c \}$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and $P(\{a, b\}) = 0$. Take $\mathcal{F'} = \{ \emptyset , \{a ,b\}, \{c\}, \Omega \} \subset \mathcal{F}$.  Define $X(a) = 1, X(b) = 1, X(c) = 2$ and $Y(a) = -1, Y(b) = -2, Y(c) = 2$. Under my definition, $Y$ is measurable in $\mathcal{F'}$ since $X \sim Y$, and $X \in \mathcal{F'}$, yet $\mathcal{F'}$ is not complete. However, I think what you said is morally true in the same way that there are different constructions of the real numbers that get at the same underlying reality of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I like your example, because it clarifies the difference. The way I see it, $Y$ is not $\mathcal{F}'$-measurable, but it trivially is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable. Do you know a reference for your definition? I also think that the distinction between the two is necessary. This way you are throwing away theoretically important questions on the existence of measurable modifications.

Comment: I usually go by intuition because my interest is more in applications than foundations. However, there is a category theoretic flavor of measure theory where "almost-functions" are objects of study. You may want to investigate the category of "Cheng measurable space" and also "almost function" on nLab. (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cheng+space). I haven't studied these theories in much detail, but I feel these sorts of questions are more investigations into logic and maybe philosophy.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Cheng spaces. It's not about logic and philosophy though, there is a famous example $X(t) = \mathbf{1} \{ B(t) = 0 \}$, the process of zeroes of Brownian motion. It is a modification of $Y(t) = 0$, but when you pass to this modification you loose all the structure of the original process.

Comment: Then I could again say something like $\max_{s \in (0, t]} X_s$ is *essentially* measurable at $F_t$ since it is equal to 1 almost surely (when $B(0) = 0$). 

The process $Y$ doesn't play any role. In my discussion, I never replaced your process $X$ with a different process $Y$. Instead, I created a random variable $Y_\infty$ which was almost everywhere equal to the random variable you were asking about, $\max_{[0,t]} X$.

Answer (score 0):

Eight months later, I revisited this question and came up with a very simple answer which satisfies me. Maybe it will also satisfy someone who is interested, so I decided to post it here.

Main trouble with understanding the gap between progressive measurability and adaptedness comes from trying to find counterexamples among nice processes (such as continuous or having some benign jumps), which are usually progressive.

In order to grasp the difference intuitively, we can take the worst (pathwise) process imaginable: real-valued $X(t)$ such that $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ are independent for $t \neq s$ and let $\mathcal{F}_t$ be its natural filtration. Consider now the following two questions:

1. being at time $t$ (= knowing $\mathcal{F}_t$), can we say whether $X(t) > 0$ or not?
2. being at time $t$, can we cay whether there was a moment $s \leq t$, such that $X(s) > 0$?

The answer to the first one is clearly yes, due to adaptedness. The second is intuitively much harder. Consider it from the computational point of view: even if the domain $T$ is discrete, so the answer is *yes*, it may take a lot of time to go through all the values of $s$ less than $t$. If, say, $T = [0, \infty)$, the answer is *no*, which means that $X(t)$ is not progressive.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your counterexample. See the second part of my answer, since the details were too long to post in this reply.